# emails editing in html: rich text editor

Tags: email, html-editor

I am trying to improve a webmail client, and i want to add a rich email editor like tnymce, ckeditor, but with support not only for compose new emails, i want to read a existing emails and respond to it.

Original emails have styles, inline images...

any suggestion? best open souce